# How to consume Json string from external API? Json returns with escaped or extra characters.

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I spent some time trying to figure this one out so I decided to post it here - hopefully it saves some time to someone else.

I'm building an ASP.Net Core Web API MVC application that accepts a Get request and makes a call to an external API (in this case is the Bing Image Search). When returning a result, it would give me a escaped Json string. Example:

```
"{\"_type\": \"Images\", \"instrumentation\": {\"pageLoadPingUrl\": \"https:...}
```

Instead of:

```
{
 "_type": "Images",
 "instrumentation": {
 "pageLoadPingUrl": "https:....
}
```

Then, I wanted to pass it back to my web client with all sort of non-successes.

I will post shortly how I solved it.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

So the issue was that I was trying to process the reponse content the wrong way. All I had to do is user the JsonConvert library.

My full API method looks like this:

```
 [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
    {
         using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "Enter your key here");

                var uri = new Uri("uri to external API here + any parameters");

                var response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
                var jsonResponse =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response); 
                return Ok(jsonResponse); 
            }
    }
```

Cheers! :)